# Re-declaration of block scoped loop variable inside the loop

Tags: javascript

I recently came across a piece of code that has me confused about the block scoped variables declared with `let` keyword inside a loop.

Consider the following code snippet:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  let i = 'hello';
  console.log(i);
}
```

How is the re-declaration of the variable `i` working here? I though, you couldn't re-declare block-scoped variables inside the same scope.

Comment: It's not the same scope.  It's a different scope per iteration.

Comment: @Taplar yes i know that but as far as i know, we shouldn't be able to re-declare `i` inside the loop.

Comment: How is it re-declaring if it is a different scope?  You're ignoring the premise you just agreed with.

Comment: It's a different scope. Are you looking for an answer with a spec citation for that, or…?

Comment: @Ry- i know that each iteration of the loop has a different scope. I guess, i am confused about whether `i` variable declared in `for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++)` is declared in a different scope that the one inside the loop's body?

Comment: Yes. That’s the different scope I was referring to.

Comment: @Ry- Oh ok, a follow up question. Is the scope in loop's body nested inside the scope in which loop variables (variables declared in loop's initialization part) are declared?

Comment: @youssaf yes, just as the scope(s) the variables declared in the loops initialization part are nested inside the scope of the function (or loop or block) the loop is in.

Comment: _You're ignoring the premise you just agreed with_ - @Taplar yeah, i realized that :P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does

```js
for(let fn = () => run; fn();) {
  let run = false;
}
```

not work? Cause every loop iteration has its own scope, so which scope will `run` inside the declaration refer to? To prevent this, the declarations in the for header are inside their own scope. Therefore you cannot access variables from within the body in the head, and as a side effect, variables can be redeclared in the body. This is specified in [13.7.4.8](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-forbodyevaluation).

Comment: The complicated declaration stuff in the spec in regard to for loops has a different purpose, though. Not that I really know a better way to answer this question… “I [thought] you couldn't re-declare block-scoped variables inside the same scope” -> “yep”?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to tell me by the code examples in your question. First one doesn't works because of the temporal dead zone. Although, the last line of your answer - _every declaration is inside of it's own scope, the body of the for loop also has it's own_ - has cleared my confusion.

Comment: @Yousaf uh, actually I was mixing this up with [function parameter initialization](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation), should've checked the spec before basing an answer on that wrong assumption. edited.

Answer (score -1):

As we can see the `let` definition here...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

`let` statement declares a block-scoped local variable.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    //blah blah blah
    let i = 'Hello'
}
```

I think this equals to `do-while` loop

```
let i = 0
do {
    // blah blah blah
    let i = 'Hello'
} while(i ++ < 10);
```

If we go back to the `let` definition, this is clear as `let` statement is block-scoped.

Hope this helps to solve your concern.